# R - can't use eigen() function in foreach() loop

Tags: r, foreach, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I've found that I'm unable to call the eigen() function in a foreach parallel loop. Here's a minimal example that fails:

```
library(doParallel)

registerDoParallel(12)

res <- foreach(s = 1:50, .combine = c)%dopar%{
    M <- matrix(rnorm(10*10), 10, 10)
    M <- M+t(M)
    E <- NULL
    E <- eigen(M)$values
    return(E)
}
```

This just freezes and never returns anything. If I comment out the eigen() line, it works fine, instantly returning a vector of NULLs.

Why is this happening? Is there some workaround or alternative eigenvalue/vector function that plays nice with foreach?

Comment: Works fine for me. I would replace the four last line by simply using `eigen(M + t(M))$values` though.

Comment: This is just for a simple reproducible example, it's not what I'm actually coding. I'm guessing maybe it's something to do with the LAPACK code running in parallel, which might vary across machines. But that's just a guess.